# SQLAlchemy: is there a "global" import statement?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

SQLAlchemy has a lot of import statements, e.g.

```
from SQLAlchemy import .....
```

Is there a "global" import statement that imports everything?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax

```
from <module> import <symbol>
```

is just one othe ways python offers to import libraries. Asexplained in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import) the expression

```
import module [as identifier]
```

is the common way to import all symbols of a module.

---

**Alternatively** you can import all symbols of a specific library using `*`:

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import *
>>> sqlalchemy.__version__
'1.3.17'
>>> engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
>>>
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I expected to work  (sorry, I was not specific enough with my original question)but if I just use "import sqlalchemy" my script doesn't work.

Comment: @JeffHeath I edited my answer with an alternative way for including all symbols. I personally tested it with a couple of attempts. Let me know if it solves your issues

Comment: (cc: @JeffHeath ) - Note that the use of `from package_name import *` is generally discouraged because it makes it more difficult to determine exactly which package is providing a given identifier. Better to `import sqlalchemy as sa` and then use `sa.create_engine`.

Comment: @GordThompson I agree with you, and it was my first answer. But OP is right when he says that in that way it doesn't work. I reproduced the `Name Error`.

Comment: I tried >>>from sqlalchemy import *, but I had to also do >>>from sqlalchemy.orm import *   and >>>from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import *.    The script works, but my IDE is complaining about all the unused modules (there must be at least 25 of them!).   We can mark this question as answered, but I would recommend to the SQLAlchemy contributors and committers that they consider reducing the number of import statements required.   Thanks for your help!